# Display graph In unity inspector window

Tags: unity-game-engine

I recently came across a video by "t3ssel8r" where he was discussing procedural animation. In the video, I saw this:

[image: inspector window on right]

That graph in the inspector window would be very helpful for what i am doing right now. The graph changes when the variables change, and would be helpful for prototyping a weapon recoil system ive been making, where the strength of the recoil (the Y value) is proportional to the amount of rounds fired (the X value).

Unfortunately, i cannot find out how to get that to display. While i could just keep using desmos, i would prefer if i could see the graph in unity. How do i get this graph to appear?

Comment: You could just use a readonly [`AnimationCurve`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationCurve.html) and update it according to the settings and use it for display only

Answer (score 3):

I found this specific demo done with custom editor script in [Second Order Dynamics by lomakinsam on GitHub](https://github.com/lomakinsam/stacking-items/tree/main/Assets/Second%20Order%20Dynamics)

[SecondOrderDemo.cs](https://github.com/lomakinsam/stacking-items/blob/main/Assets/Second%20Order%20Dynamics/Demo/SecondOrderDemo.cs) is the one which you shared the screenshot.

It has one script for inspector/editor script which does the graph thing [SecondOrderDemoInspector.cs](https://github.com/lomakinsam/stacking-items/blob/main/Assets/Second%20Order%20Dynamics/Demo/SecondOrderDemoInspector.cs)