# how do I display a graph in the unity inspector

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

I've written a script that takes linear acceleration of a game object and performs movement based on a curve. I wanted to know if there is a way I can render the graph in the inspector as it'll make it easier to visualize what my code is doing.

So for example:
On ice. acceleration begins lower but increases over time). I achieved this by using a Bezier curve. To summarize what that is: I have a graph representing speed over time. The first point is the origin (0,0) - a game object at rest. A second point (x,y) representing the max speed and how long I want it to take to reach max speed. And a third point which is where the magic happens that turns the straight line from point 1 and 2 into a curve. The thing is visualizing the curve would aid greatly in identifying the behavior of the game objects acceleration as it gets closer to max speed.
Is there a way to display the graph of this function in the inspector so that changes made to the 3 points are shown to me in editor?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display graph In unity inspector window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75014104/display-graph-in-unity-inspector-window)

Comment: Yes, this is done using [Custom Editors](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/editor-CustomEditors.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using an [animation curve](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/EditingCurves.html). You will be able to modify this curve in a visual way. Here is an example of what it looks like in the inspector:

[image]

You can then use this curve for many applications, despite the name inferring that you can only use the curve for animation. Here is a [great video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=roWiGo1Hpfk) explaining animation curves in Unity.

See also [`AnimationCurve` API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationCurve.html)